# Multiple In-App purchase ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am trying to achieve something like shopping cart in iOS where I can buy multiple SKUs from already defined SKUs in itunes connect.

Like this:

```
NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                               @"com.myapp.c",
                               @"com.myapp.d",
                               @"com.myapp.a",
                               @"com.myapp.s",
                               @"com.myapp.b",
                               @"com.myapp.h",
                               nil];
```

Where c,d,a etc are all SKUs defined in iTunes Connect.

1) When a user is clicking "Buy" button, can I call all SKUs like in a set or array and achieve this in a single call to iTunes Sandbox or do I have to do multiple calls to get the values ?

2) And can I show the addition of all SKUs in the pop up basket to buy them?

Comment: Hey you can go with this awesome tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial hope that would be helpful for you

Comment: Thanks ! That is helpful.